# jQuery get value of child and set value of input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set the value of a input box based on the click event on a list. I'm using `$("#modifyText2").val()` to set the value of the input field, and it works. But I can't get the text of the `div.CompanyName`

`.CompanyName` is a child of `.shop_data`

What I've tried:

```
$("#shops_output").on("click", ".shop_data", function() {
    $("#modifyText2").val(this.children(".CompanyName").text);
});
```

Comment: `this.children(".CompanyName").text()`

Comment: Also, `this.children(".CompanyName")[0].text()` if there are multiple children with same class

Comment: What you can try is have a look at the browser console to better understand the error occurred and share the error message so that anyone can better identify the problem.

Comment: Please see this demo: http://underudvikling.dk/ajax/eksempler/ajax/index.php - Click the search button and select one of the radio buttons... I'm looking to populate #modifyText2 with the value of the clicked .shop_data element child . CompanyName's inner text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `.children()` is a jQuery function.

Therefore you'll need to use `$(this)` instead of the plain ol' `this`, since there is no `children` function attached to the normal javascript object.

Wrapping `this` in the jQuery `$` function is what adds all of the extra methods provided by jQuery.

```
$("#shops_output").on("click", ".shop_data", function() {
    $("#modifyText2").val($(this).children(".CompanyName").text());
});
```

Specifically: `$(this).children(".CompanyName").text()`

Also, this only works if only one child is matched. If there is multiple, as mentioned by others, you will need to do the following:

```
$($(this).children(".CompanyName")[0]).text()

// or

$(this).children(".CompanyName").eq(0).text()
```

Comment: It's close to working. Please see the demo here: http://underudvikling.dk/ajax/eksempler/ajax/index.php - Click search and select one of the radio buttons. It's modifying my input field, but with nothing instead of the value...

Comment: Changed a DIV to a SPAN and now it works fine :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or in the jQuery way `$(this).find('.CompanyName').eq(0).html()` if the content of ".CompanyName" is just text.